# multiple relationships with same table by Dataannotation with code first

Tags: ef-code-first, data-annotations, one-to-many, one-to-one

I have the following model:

```
public class Member
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Username { get; set; }

  public int MainEmailId { get; set; }
  public virtual Email MainEmail { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Email> MemberEmails { get; set; }
}

public partial class Email
{
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Email { get; set; }

  public int MemberId { get; set; }
  public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see I wish to create a:
one-to-one relation from the Member to MemberEmail (the main email address)
one-to-many relation from Member to MemberEmail

I know how to do this with Code First Fluent API. However I need to do it with DataAnnotations only. Is this possible?

Thanks a lot.